# swift http request crash nil value

Tags: swift, http

I am using the following code to retrieve a response from a php page. Its works fine except every once in a while it crashes with an error after recieveing a nil value on the following line:

> let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)

is there a way I can catch this?

```html
let myUrl = NSURL(string: "https://*****backend/newmessage.php")
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: myUrl! as URL)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        let postString = "userid=\(userid!)"
        
        print(postString)
        request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
            data, response, error in
            DispatchQueue.global(qos: DispatchQoS.QoSClass.default).async {
                let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
                if error != nil {
                    print("Error: \(error)")
                }
                DispatchQueue.main.async() {
                    
                    print(responseString!)
                    
                    if (responseString! == "NEW"){
                        
                        self.messageIcon.setImage(UIImage(named: "newmessage.png"), for: UIControlState.normal)
                        
                    }else{
                        
                        
                        self.messageIcon.setImage(UIImage(named: "envelope.png"), for: UIControlState.normal)
                        
                        
                    }
                    
                    
                }
            }
        }
        task.resume()
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not address a potential nil w/ an `if-else` statement? Alternatively, you could use a `guard` statement.

`if responseString != nil { // do stuff } else { // do other stuff}`